# Template class, function specialization

Tags: c++, templates

I want to have a template class that looks something like what I have down below. Then, I want a function in it with a template specialization depending on a CLASS template parameter. How do I make this work? I realize the code I provided is wrong on many levels, but it's just to illustrate the concept.

```
template <typename _T, size_t num>
class Foo
{
    // If num == 1, I want to call this function...
    void Func<_T, 1>()
    {
        printf("Hi!");
    }

    // Otherwise, I want to call this version.
    void Func<_T, num>()
    {
        printf("Hello world!");
    }
};
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
struct Otherwise { };
template<size_t> struct C : Otherwise { };

// don't use _Uppercase - those names are reserved for the implementation
// (i removed the '_' char)
template <typename T, size_t num>
class Foo
{
public:
    void Func() { Func(C<num>()); }

private:
    // If num == 1, I want to call this function...
    void Func(C<1>)
    {
        printf("Hi 1!");
    }

    // If num == 2, I want to call this function...
    void Func(C<2>)
    {
        printf("Hi 2!");
    }

    // Otherwise, I want to call this version.
    void Func(Otherwise)
    {
        printf("Hello world!");
    }

    //// alternative otherwise solution:
    // template<size_t I>
    // void Func(C<I>) { .. }
};
```

Comment: I like this solution. I even learned something about C++ naming convention! However, how do I do this if I have, say, any number of specializations for various values of num along with a fall-back in case none of them work?

Comment: Wow that worked amazingly. Are you like, a boost developer or something? Templates are nasty beasts.

Answer (score 2):

There are no partial specialisations of function
templates, and to partially specialise a member you need to first
partially specialise the class template.

```
template< typename _T, size_t num >
struct Foo {
    void Func() {
        printf("Hello world!");
    }
};

template< typename _T >
struct Foo< _T, 1 > {
    void Func() {
        printf("Hi!");
    }
};
```

Now, if `Foo` also contains methods other than `Func` whose implementation is independent of the value for `num`, and you don't want to duplicate their implementation in the specialization of `Foo`, you can apply the following pattern:

```
template< typename _T, size_t num >
struct FooFuncBase {
    void Func() {
        printf("Hello world!");
    }
};

template< typename _T >
struct FooFuncBase< _T, 1 > {
    void Func() {
        printf("Hi!");
    }
};

template< typename _T, size_t num >
struct Foo : public FooFuncBase< _T, num > {
  void OtherFuncWhoseImplementationDoesNotDependOnNum() {
    ...
  }
};
```

Or, using [CRTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern):

```
template< typename _Derived, typename _T, size_t num >
struct FooFuncBase {
    void Func() {
        static_cast< _Derived* >(this)->OtherFuncWhoseImplementationDoesNotDependOnNum();
        printf("Hello world!");
    }
};

template< typename _Derived, typename _T >
struct FooFuncBase< _Derived, _T, 1 > {
    void Func() {
        static_cast< _Derived* >(this)->OtherFuncWhoseImplementationDoesNotDependOnNum();
        printf("Hi!");
    }
};

template< typename _T, size_t num >
struct Foo : public FooFuncBase< Foo< _T, num >, _T, num > {
  void OtherFuncWhoseImplementationDoesNotDependOnNum() {
    printf("Other");
  }
};
```

Comment: It is a class that is being specialised in this case, the OP just doesn't know how to write the syntax for that I think.

Comment: I think there's more to it, let's see what he answers. I'm almost certain he only needs to specialize a subset of `Foo`'s methods, not the entire class.

Comment: I like the solution, but I think it's quite hackish to put the "special case code" in the public interface and all the general code in the base. Surely there's a better way!

Comment: What if Func depends on members declared in Foo?

Answer (score 1):

This is called  partial template specialisation. It looks like this:

```
template<typename _T, size_t num>
class FooBase
{
};

template <typename _T, size_t num>
class Foo : public FooBase<_T,num>
{
    void Func()
    {
        printf("Hello world!");
    }
};


template <typename _T>
class Foo<_T,1> : public FooBase<_T,num>
{
    void Func()
    {
        printf("Hi!");
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't want to duplicate the full body of Foo (there's many other methods in there that I've omitted) in each specialization.

Comment: Edited to allow for functions in a base class.